# C++ friend operator+ overloading

Tags: c++, overloading, friend, operator-keyword

I'm confused about friend operator overloading.  It has no problem if I write the friend operator overloading function within the header file, but it gives me the following errors once I moved the function to class file. I googled some samples and they all written the function in the header file. What did I do wrong? Thanks.

```
...: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
...: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘statisticain’ with no type
...: error: ‘main_savitch_2C::statistician operator+(int)’ must have an argument of class or enumerated type


// a.h
class A
{
    public:
        friend A operator + (const A &a1, const A &a2);
};

// a.cpp
#include "a.h"
A operator + (const A &a1, const A &a2)
{
    //
}
```

Comment: That code works fine for me.  What does your **actual** code look like?

Comment: Since everybody is giving advice on how to overload operator+ correctly, [here's](http://codepad.org/8E9m5A7a) my advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error message you're getting:

```
ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘statisticain’ with no type
```

I think that you misspelled "statistician" by reversing the last two letters (note that you have "statisticain" instead of "statistician.")

This should have nothing to do with whether `operator+` is implemented in the header or the .cpp file.

Comment: Oh yeah, i didn't read the error message carefully. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the previous answer. Also, if I may ask, why make the function a `friend` when both arguments and the return type are of the same class? why not make it a member so the first argument is passed implicitly by the `this` operator?

Comment: @darkphoenix- (This probably belongs as a comment rather than an answer, BTW).  You would make the `operator +` function a free function rather than a member function so that if there are implicit conversions from some other type to `A`, then the operator can be considered.  If it were a member, then if the first operand weren't an `A`, the function wouldn't be found.  It would be a `friend` if it needed access to class data members.

Answer (score 0):

Move the two param version out of the class declaration.  Or just use one param and the this pointer.

Here's an abbreviated real world example.

```
//complexnumber.h 
    class ComplexNumber
    {
        float _r;
        float _i;

        friend ComplexNumber operator+(const ComplexNumber&, const ComplexNumber&);

        public:
            ComplexNumber(float real, float img):_r(real),_i(img) {}
            ComplexNumber& operator + (const ComplexNumber &other);
    };

    ComplexNumber operator+(const ComplexNumber &c1, const ComplexNumber& c2);


//complexnumber.h 
    ComplexNumber operator+(const ComplexNumber &c1, const ComplexNumber& c2)
    {
        return ComplexNumber(c1._r+c2._r, c1._i+c2._i);
    }


    // static
    ComplexNumber& ComplexNumber::operator + (const ComplexNumber &other)
    {
        this->_r = this->_r + other._r;
        this->_i = this->_i + other._i;

        return *this;

    }
```

Comment: @selbie- From the C++ ISO spec, 13.5.6: "An operator function shall either be a **non-static** member function or be a non-member function and have at least one parameter whose type is a class, a reference to a class, an enumeration, or a reference to an enumeration."  Looks like you actually can't make overloaded operators static, though I had no idea this was the case until I looked it up.

Comment: Even if you could do that, what would be the advantage?  And your member function version is very wrong.  It modifies it's left operand.  operator+ should not do that.

Comment: Oops, my first iteration was incorrect.  Updated version above.